Модуль NEAT в python. В чём ошибка?
Подскажите пожалуйста в чём ошибка в коде. Решил написать змейку которая играет сама в себя с помощью модуля neat. Вот код на питон и вот код конфигурации.
import random
import neat

# Глобальные переменные
max_score = 0
box_height = 20  # Высота поля игры
box_width = 40  # Ширина поля игры
snake = [(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3)]  # Начальное положение змейки
food = (5, 10)  # Начальное положение еды

# Функция для создания новой еды
def create_food(snake):
    food = None
    while food is None:
        food = (random.randint(1, box_height - 2), random.randint(1, box_width - 2))
        if food in snake:
            food = None
    if food is None:
        food = (1, 1)  # Задаем координаты еды по умолчанию
    return food


# Функция для движения змейки
def move(direction, snake):
    head = snake[0]
    y, x = head
    if direction == "UP":
        new_head = (y - 1, x)
    elif direction == "DOWN":
        new_head = (y + 1, x)
    elif direction == "LEFT":
        new_head = (y, x - 1)
    elif direction == "RIGHT":
        new_head = (y, x + 1)
    return [new_head] + snake[:-1]

# Функция для проверки столкновений
def check_collision(snake):
    head = snake[0]
    if head in snake[1:] or head[0] in [0, box_height - 1] or head[1] in [0, box_width - 1]:
        return True
    return False

# Основная функция игры
def run_game(genomes, config):
    global max_score
    max_score = 0
    for genome_id, genome in genomes:
        net = neat.nn.FeedForwardNetwork.create(genome, config)
        direction = "RIGHT"
        score = 0
        snake = [(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3)]  # Начальное положение змейки
        food = create_food(snake)
        while True:
            inputs = [snake[0][0], snake[0][1], food[0], food[1]]
            output = net.activate(inputs)
            direction_index = output.index(max(output))
            if direction_index == 0:
                direction = "UP"
            elif direction_index == 1:
                direction = "DOWN"
            elif direction_index == 2:
                direction = "LEFT"
            elif direction_index == 3:
                direction = "RIGHT"
            snake = move(direction, snake)
            if check_collision(snake):
                break
            if snake[0] == food:
                snake.append(snake[-1])
                food = create_food(snake)
                score += 1
                max_score = max(max_score, score)
            genome.fitness = score


# Настройка NEAT
config = neat.config.Config(neat.DefaultGenome, neat.DefaultReproduction,
                            neat.DefaultSpeciesSet, neat.DefaultStagnation,
                            'config.txt')
population = neat.Population(config)

# Запуск NEAT
population.run(run_game, 50)

[NEAT]
fitness_criterion = max
fitness_threshold = 3.9
pop_size = 150
reset_on_extinction = False

[DefaultGenome]
# node activation options
activation_default = sigmoid
activation_mutate_rate = 0.0
activation_options = sigmoid
# node aggregation options
aggregation_default = sum
aggregation_mutate_rate = 0.0
aggregation_options = sum
# node bias options
bias_init_mean = 0.0
bias_init_stdev = 1.0
bias_max_value = 30.0
bias_min_value = -30.0
bias_mutate_power = 0.5
bias_mutate_rate = 0.7
bias_replace_rate = 0.1
# genome compatibility options
compatibility_disjoint_coefficient = 1.0
compatibility_weight_coefficient = 0.5
# connection add/remove rates
conn_add_prob = 0.5
conn_delete_prob = 0.5
# connection enable options
enabled_default = True
enabled_mutate_rate = 0.01
feed_forward = True
initial_connection = full
# node add/remove rates
node_add_prob = 0.2
node_delete_prob = 0.2
# network parameters
num_hidden = 0
num_inputs = 4
num_outputs = 1
# node response options
response_init_mean = 1.0
response_init_stdev = 0.0
response_max_value = 30.0
response_min_value = -30.0
response_mutate_power = 0.0
response_mutate_rate = 0.0
response_replace_rate = 0.0
# connection weight options
weight_init_mean = 0.0
weight_init_stdev = 1.0
weight_max_value = 30
weight_min_value = -30
weight_mutate_power = 0.5
weight_mutate_rate = 0.8
weight_replace_rate = 0.1
[DefaultSpeciesSet]
compatibility_threshold = 3.0
[DefaultStagnation]
species_fitness_func = max
max_stagnation = 20
species_elitism = 2
[DefaultReproduction]
elitism = 2
survival_threshold = 0.2

и вся эта история выдаёт ошибку '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'. Буду очень признателен если поможете)))
